# Spring Data locking

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data

I am using `CrudRepository` with methods annotated with `@Lock`. This will result in shared/exclusive locks on row(s). The underlying DB is Postgresql 9.4. But is there a way to lock the whole table for the transaction?

UPDATE:
The problem why I want to lock a whole table:
Consider a table containing rows with a single value, an integer. Every transaction has to compute the sum of the values in the table, and insert the sum as a new row. The next transaction has to compute the sum of the values again, but now with the newly inserted value.

There may be a better solution, other ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that? Locking a whole table is usually not a good idea and should only be considered as a  "last resort"

Comment: Yes, I want to use it as a last resort. I know there is some serious performance penalty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this when you open transaction:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("LOCK TABLE public.table_name IN
EXCLUSIVE MODE").executeUpdate();
```

Of course PostgreSQL specific, but you have also specific problem